# A normal ring (possibly a non-domain) is integrally closed in its total ring of fractions

Tags: commutative-algebra, localization

$\newcommand\frp{\mathfrak{p}}$I am trying to understand [034M](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/034M) of the Stacks Project, whose statement is the title of this post. The proof seems to implicitly assume that $R$ is a subring of $R_\frp$ (in the sentence “as $R \subset R_{\frp}$ is
flat we see that $R_{\frp} \subset Q(R) \otimes_R R_{\frp}$”). However, this is not the case for a non-domain $R$ (the preimage of the prime $(0)\subset R_\frp$ along $R\to R_\frp$ is prime and thus different to $(0)\subset R$). So what is going on?

After looking for a while on MSE, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3138464/394668) is the only related thing I've found and it seems not to be of help.

---

This is what I've tried so far: Let $\frp\subset R$ be any prime and consider [this commutative diagram](https://q.uiver.app/#q=WzAsNSxbMCwwLCJSIl0sWzEsMCwiUShSKSJdLFswLDEsIlJfXFxtYXRoZnJha3twfSJdLFsxLDEsIlEoUilfXFxtYXRoZnJha3twfSJdLFsyLDEsIlEoUl9cXG1hdGhmcmFre3B9KSJdLFswLDEsIiIsMCx7InN0eWxlIjp7InRhaWwiOnsibmFtZSI6Imhvb2siLCJzaWRlIjoidG9wIn19fV0sWzIsMywiIiwwLHsic3R5bGUiOnsidGFpbCI6eyJuYW1lIjoiaG9vayIsInNpZGUiOiJ0b3AifX19XSxbMyw0LCIiLDAseyJzdHlsZSI6eyJ0YWlsIjp7Im5hbWUiOiJob29rIiwic2lkZSI6InRvcCJ9fX1dLFsxLDNdLFswLDJdXQ==):

[image]

where the first (resp., the second) bottom arrow is an inclusion because localization is exact (resp., because the map $H$ [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/99831/101848) is always injective). Suppose $x\in Q(R)$ satisfies an integral equation over $R$. Then we can map this equation to $Q(R_\frp)$ to deduce that the image of $x$ in $Q(R_\frp)$ is integral over $R$ and hence over $R_\mathfrak{p}$. Since we are assuming that $R_\mathfrak{p}$ is a normal domain, it follows that the image $y$ of $x$ in $Q(R)_\mathfrak{p}$ is actually in $R_\mathfrak{p}$.

Define the ideal $I=\{f\in R\mid fx\in R\}$ of $R$. We want to show that $I$ is not contained in any prime ideal of $R$. To look for a contradiction, suppose $I\subset\frp$ for some prime $\frp\subset R$. Write $x=g/s$ inside $Q(R)$. In particular, $s\in I$. We can write $y=a/t$ for some $a\in\frp$ and $t\in R\setminus\frp$. We have $g=sy=sa/t$ in $R_\frp$, so there is $u\in R\setminus\frp$ such that $gtu=sau$ in $R$. Hence, $g\in\frp$.

And now, what? I don't know what else to deduce, or if this is the right way at all.

Comment: I'm not sure I got what you said. I claim that $x$ belongs to the field of fractions of $R_p$ since $s/1$ is not zero in $R_p$, and $x$ can be written as $\frac{g/1}{s/1}$. Moreover, $x$ is integral over $R_p$ since it is integral over $R$, so $x$ belongs to $R_p$. Then there is $t\in R\setminus p$ such that $tx\in R$, a contradiction.

Comment: In fact, I don't get what you mean by $Q(R)_p$. This could be a localization of $Q(R)$ as an $R$-module, but why should I care about it?

Comment: @user26857 Thank you very much. Answering your last comment: the thing is that the total ring of fractions is not a functor: in general a ring homo $A\to B$ does not induce a ring homo $Q(A)\to Q(B)$, let alone one that makes the corresponding square commute (this boils down to the observation that ring homos do not preserve nonzerodivisors in general). However, if $S\subset A$ is any multiplicative set, then the ring homo $\varphi:A\to S^{-1}A$ does preserve nonzerodivisors and it induces a ring homo $Q(\varphi):Q(A)\to Q(S^{-1}A)$ that makes the corresponding square commute.

Comment: Alternatively, $Q(\varphi)=H\circ\varphi_\mathfrak{p}$, where $H$ is the map from the linked post. I was just being very explicit about this because I was finding out about how to work with localizations at two different multiplicative subsets $S,T$ such that none of $S,T$ is a subset of the other (by this I mean that there might be no $R$-algebra maps between $Q(R)$ and $R_\mathfrak{p}$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\def\frp{\mathfrak{p}}$EDIT (24/8/23): Johan [corrected](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/034M#comment-8528) the typo: the map $R\to R_\frp$ is always flat (since it is a localization map), regardless of whether it is injective or not. From here, the rest of the SP's proof is sound. (I guess I had a [compiling error](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/advice-on-writing-papers/on-compilation-errors-in-mathematical-reading-and-how-to-resolve-them/) and my mind halted the first time I read the proof and saw “$R\subset R_\frp$.”)

Here's a little bit more detail in the SP's proof: flatness tells us that $R_\frp\cong R\otimes_RR_\frp\to Q(R)\otimes_RR_\frp\cong S^{-1}(R_\frp)$ is injective, where $S\subset R_\frp$ is the image in $R_\frp$ of the set of nonzerodivisors of $R$. Note that $S^{-1}(R_\frp)\subset Q(R)$ (this is because a localization map always preserve nonzerodivisors). These identifications is what allows to write in the proof “as $R_\frp$ is normal we see that $x\otimes 1\in Q(R)\otimes_R R_\frp$ is an element of $R_\frp$.”

---

Btw, note that the converse is false in general: there are rings that are integrally closed in its total field of fractions while not being normal (the ring $R=\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ satisfies $Q(R)=R$; on the other hand, $R$ has a unique prime $\mathfrak{p}=(2)\subset R$, but $R_\mathfrak{p}=R$ is not a domain).

However, the converse turns out to be true if we add the hypotheses of $R$ reduced and finitely many minimal primes, see [030C](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/030C).